# Rating module makes an input radio change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rating module on my webpage :

```
<div class="rating">
   <label for="rate_1"class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"><input type="radio" id="rate_1" name="rating" value="1"></label>
   <label for="rate_2"class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"><input type="radio" id="rate_2" name="rating" value="2"></label>
   <label for="rate_3"class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"><input type="radio" id="rate_3" name="rating" value="3"></label>
   <label for="rate_4"class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"><input type="radio" id="rate_4" name="rating" value="4"></label>
   <label for="rate_5"class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"><input type="radio" id="rate_5" name="rating" value="5"></label>
</div>
```

and when I click on 4th or 5th star, I would like the validated radio been checked in my validation :

```
<ul class="validation">
     <li class="success-hover"><label for="id_validation_1"><input class="success" type="radio" id="id_validation_1" name="validation"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Validated</label></li>
     <li class="danger-hover"><label for="id_validation_2"><input class="danger" type="radio" id="id_validation_2" name="validation"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Rejected</label></li>
     <li class="info-hover"><label for="id_validation_3"><input type="radio" id="id_validation_3" name="validation"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>Partially completed</label></li>
     <li class="warning-hover"><label for="id_validation_4"><input type="radio" id="id_validation_4" name="validation"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Expired</label></li>
</ul>
```

I started with some Jquery code :

```
if ($("input[name=rating][value=4]").prop('checked', true)||$("input[name=rating][value=5]").prop('checked', true)) {
    $('.success').prop('checked', true);
}
else $('.success').prop('checked', false);
```

But it doesn't work... Please help me ! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `.is(":checked")` to check if the radio input is checked
   or not.
2. `.prop('checked', true)` cannot be used in condition statement as it doesn't return a boolean result. It is used to set the status of radio button as checked.

> http://jsfiddle.net/02gocfr1/

**JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name=rating]").change(function () {
        if ($("input[name=rating][value=4]").is(":checked") || $("input[name=rating][value=5]").is(":checked")) {
            $('.success').prop('checked', true);
        } else $('.success').prop('checked', false);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is using the `prop()` setter, not the getter.

Also note that you can make your selectors shorter as the radio inputs have `id` attributes, and you can use a single call to set the `.success` `checked` property as the result of your condition is a boolean value. Try this:

```
$('.success').prop('checked', $("#rate_4").prop('checked') || $("#rate_5").prop('checked'));
```